# Storing a set of tuples in Redis vs Cassandra

Tags: redis, cassandra

Let's suppose we need to store multiple sets of tuples:

```
A=((x,'a'), (y,'d'), (z,'g'))
B=((y, 'b'), (z,'e'))
C=((x, 'c'), (w, 'f'))
```

In Cassandra column family with  sets of tuples would like this:

```
OrderedSetsCF   ->
    A    ->  (x='a'),(y='d'),(z='g')
    B    ->  (y='b'),(z='e')
    C    ->  (x='c'), (w='f')
```

Redis is actually very similar to Cassandra in terms of its support for sets. A set in Redis can only have strings, so to support tuples you'd have to store values separately. From what I found, in Redis this would look like this:

```
A=(x,y,z)
B=(y,z)
C=(x,w)
A:x='a'
A:y='d'
A:z='g'
B:y='b'
B:z='e'
C:x='c'
C:w='f'
```

Is there really no other way to store a set of tuples in Redis without denormalizing like this ?

Comment: Why are you not using a Redis *sorted set* in order to associate the string element with a number? http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: Oh I should have been more clear. The value is not a number. I will edit the question.

Comment: In this case you can't use the Hash type since you need order?

Comment: Good point, but i don't think I can use hashes for the reason that I may have way more tuples. The manual (http://redis.io/topics/data-types) says: "A hash with a few fields (where few means up to one hundred or so) is stored in a way that takes very little space, so you can store millions of objects in a small Redis instance." But this is a valid point, I may use it for the storage of the tupple values.

Comment: I found this post that is pointing me in the right direction. I think I am getting close to an answer.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404847/how-to-get-all-keys-that-match-a-specific-pattern-from-a-hash-in-redis

Comment: @OlegDulin did you find the answer?